# How to inform Windows that the service has started?

Tags: node.js, windows-services

I am running a nodejs HTTP server packaged as an exe binary with the pkg npm module. I need to run it as a windows service. It works perfectly when started normally. But here is what happens if I run it as a windows service:

- I start the service.
- Windows attempts to start the service.
- During this time, the HTTP server is accessible, and works perfectly
- Windows services times out with the error after 30 seconds: "The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion."

It seems to me that I somehow have to inform windows that my service has started, let me just stay open.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

A regular application can't work as Windows service. As [the reference states](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Services/service-programs), the implementation should satisfy certain requirements,

> the interface requirements of the service control manager (SCM) that a service program must include:
>
> Service Entry Point
>
> Service ServiceMain Function
>
> Service Control Handler Function

There is [`os-service`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/os-service) package that allows to install a service that starts Node.js script. Current script is considered entry point by default:

```
const osService = require('os-service');

const [action] = process.argv.slice(2);

function errorHandler(err) {
  if (!err) return;
  console.error(err);
  process.exit(1);
}

if (action === '--install') {
  osService.add('Foo', errorHandler);
} else if (action === '--uninstall') {
  osService.remove('Foo', errorHandler);
} else {
  // report service as running
  osService.run('Foo', () => {
    osService.stop();
  });

  // app entry point
}
```